# Having trouble positioning android dynamically loaded buttons

Tags: android, button, dynamic, position

I'm creating buttons dynamically in my class, I try to position them using 'offsetLeftAndRight()' or '.leftMargin' and '.topMargin' as follows,

```
public class instruction extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.instruct);
    final Button btn = new Button(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsd2 = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    paramsd2.leftMargin = 500;
    paramsd2.topMargin = 500;


    paramsd2.height = 60;
    paramsd2.width = 200;

    btn.offsetLeftAndRight(300);

    btn.setLayoutParams(paramsd2);
    addContentView(btn, paramsd2);

}
```

But the button always stays in the top left corner, how can I position it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: be aware that you are setting twice the width and height of your button : in the layoutparams constructor you set it to WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT, and you set it again to 60, 200 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddContentView()` is not the proper way to add a view in an already set layout.

make your main layout a RelativeLayout (check this in the instruct.xml layout file)
use its id to retreive a reference on it in your `onCreate()` method using

```
myRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.itsId)
```

then add your button to this layout :

```
myRelativeLayout.addView(myButton);
```

the layout params of your button seems fine for positioning so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Set margin on button rather then layout

```
 MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(backToMainScreenImageView.getLayoutParams());
marginParams.setMargins(0, 0, (int) UIUtil.getRadialButtonMainMargin(this), 0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
backToMainScreenImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
paramsd2.setMargin(500, 500, 0, 0);
btn.setLayoutParams(paramsd2);
```